# Any other way to access node/express data in `req.session` without relying on `req`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, authentication, express

Is there a way to set/get from session without requiring me to pass `app` or `req` all the way into my service...?

See `auth.service.js` near the bottom in `saveAuthToken (...) { ... }`.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(session({
  store: new FileStore({ path: '.tmp' }),
  secret: '12345ABCDE',
}));

app.use('/', require('index'));
app.use('/login', require('login/login'));

module.exports = app;
```

**login.js**

```
'use strict';

var _ = require('lodash');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var authService = require('../services/auth.service');

router.get('/', get);
router.post('/', post);

module.exports = router;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function get (req, res, next) {
  res.render('login/login', { title: 'Login' });
}

function post (req, res, next) {
  var credentials = {
    username: req.param('username'),
    password: req.param('password')
  };

  authService.getTokenByLogin(credentials).then(success).catch(error);

  ////////////

  function success () {
    res.redirect('dashboard');
  }

  function error (err) {
    res.render('error', { error: err });
  }
}
```

**auth.service.js**

```
'use strict';

var _ = require('lodash');
var http = require('request-promise');

module.exports = {
  getTokenByLogin: getTokenByLogin
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function getTokenByLogin (credentials) {
  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'http://domain/login/credentials',
    form: credentials,
    json: true
  };
  return http(options).then(success);

  ////////////

  function success (data) {
    saveAuthToken(data);
    return data;

    ////////////

    function saveAuthToken (token) {
      req.session.token = _.cloneDeep(token); //how else...?
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to pass something.  You can pass the `req.session` object instead, but there can be many requests in flight at the same time so you have to pass state for this particular request to any code that needs it.  You can't stuff it into a global somewhere.

Comment: To have a session, you would also have to have a request, so it makes sense to pass that request object along to anything that needs it, and in your code it seems quite simple, and only a function call away with `authService.getTokenByLogin(req)`, and you could access `req.param` in the function as well.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense that `req` is required. Now I'm wondering if there's a better way to track/store a temporary user instance.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways

1. do your way (pass req to function)
2. use global parameter like this

   global.session = req.session // declare

   console.log(global.session) // use this value from any file